# Conditional Probability lost card problem.

Tags: probability

Q : **A card from a pack of 52 cards is lost. From the remaining cards of the
pack, two cards are drawn. What is the probability that they both are
diamonds?**

**My Approach :** I calculated the probability of selecting 2 diamonds when A Diamond card is lost and added it to the probability of selecting 2 diamonds when a diamond card is not lost.

P($\frac{D}{LD})$ + P($\frac{D}{NLD}$) $= \frac{^{12}C_2}{^{51}C_2} + \frac{^{13}C_2}{^{51}C_2}$

$=\frac{48}{425}$

But the answer given in the book is $\frac{1}{17}$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Note that the lost card does not matter.  It might as well be on the bottom of the pack.

Answer (score 2):

We use your analysis, with some correction. Let $T$ be the event $2$ diamonds, and let $L$ be the event it was a diamond that was lost. Then
$$\Pr(T)=\Pr(T\mid L)\Pr(L)+\Pr(T\mid L^c)\Pr(L^c).$$
Note that $\Pr(L)=1/4$ and $\Pr(L^c)=3/4$.

Your expressions for $\Pr(T\mid L)$ and $\Pr(T\mid L^c)$ are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, intuitively, it's like saying, instead of drawing the top two cards after shuffling, move the top one to the bottom and reveal card 2 and 3. What's the probability that these two are diamonds?
$$\frac{\binom{13}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}} = \frac{1}{17}.$$
This is symmetry.

Comment: why is the lost card included in the combinations?

Comment: @prakharlondhe: As the answer says, this is an alternative approach: there **is no** lost card, just one we moved to the bottom of the deck. In that case, it's clear that the card should still be included. The last step, then, is to convince yourself that "skipping one card, moving it to the bottom" is *mathematically* no different to "losing one card".

Answer (score 1):

I partitioned the cases and then used the Law of Total probability instead of using combinations.  Apologies if you need an approach that uses combinations.

The approach:

Let $P(X)$ be the probability of the lost card being a diamond ($=1/4$)

Let $P(Y)$ be the probability of the lost card not being a diamond ($=3/4$)

In the case of event $X$ (the lost card is a diamond), the probability of selecting 2 cards and having them both be a diamond under condition $X$ is then:

$P(2D | X) = (12/51)*(11/50)=(22/425)$

Under condition $Y$:

$P(2D | Y) = (13/51)*(12/50)=(26/425)$

With the four aforementioned probabilities, we can use the Law of Total probability to obtain the textbook's answer:

$P(2D) = P(2D | X)P(X) + P(2D | Y)P(Y) = (22/425)(1/4)+(26/425)(3/4) = 1/17$

(According to Wolfram Alpha).

Comment: That's where I got silly I think... I didn't multiply it with respective probabilities $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$... This then yields the same answer... thank you..